# Blank page when uploading website files to web hoster

Tags: html, indexing, web-hosting

So I downloaded my own portfolio after making it through a portfolio maker and decided to download it, modify the html files to my liking and then wanted to upload them to a web hoster where I would use my own domain for it, however when I tried uploading my files to the main folder on my website's directory and check the website out it simply shows me a blank page, even though it actually displays my logo on the tab on top. When I open the index.html with Chrome from my local files it displays my website perfectly however when I upload it to my website and try view it that's when I get a problem. I have tried using 2 different web hosters and tried uploading my files through FTP and direct upload and still got the same blank page.

NOTE: I uploaded all the files in my site folder not just the index.html and if it works when I opened it with Chrome I don't see why it wouldn't work on my website.

[image: Screenshot of blank page]

[image: Screenshot of my website when I open it with chrome from my local files]

Comment: Make sure to upload your files to the "web root" of your web server, the exact setup depends on your hoster. Edit: quick Google suggests the content has to be inside the folder `/public_html/`

Comment: If you look in the browser console there are a lot of errors, looks like jquery isn't loaded?

Comment: thank you for your comment Rob, and yes, I made sure to upload everything into the public_html folder but that wasn't the issue as I still got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to upload some files:

[image]

All the ones marked `404` are missing and need to be uploaded.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how come I forgot if I uploaded everything on my website's folder onto the web hoster?

Comment: I don't know I guess something has modified your html to use local files?

Comment: alright thank you, I'll look into the files and see if something is pointing torwards a local file in a specific path